# REST API not finding Item just created

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, rest, sharepoint-rest-api

I have a list that if certain conditions are met will create 1 item each in 2 separate lists in a different SharePoint site collection.  I have enabled the '**recursive workflow**' successfully in a different site collection but the 'Source Library' and 'Destination list' are in the same site collection.

Using The POST METHOD for the REST API "**_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('{ListName}')/items**" I am able to update the 2 lists passing the values in local variables, using separate calls & dictionaries of course.  I have added the Source Workflow to the App Permissions of the Destination Site Collection.  When I try to find the list item that was just created by the workflow to (fire off the recursive email notification Workflow in the Destination list) using "**_api/web/lists(guid'XXXXXXXX-AAAA-YYYY-BBBB-ZZZZZZZZZZZZ')/items?$filter=Title%20eq%20'[%Current Item:Project Title%]'&$top=1&$select=ID**".

I log That my call returns something by "count items" and I see "Number of Titles of the Item we just entered = 1".  I use the "**GET d/results(0) from Variable:responseContent output to Variable:NewItemDictionary**" then next line is "**Get Id from NewItemDictionary output to Variable:NewID**".  Since there is only 1 items, for Grins I also use the **Get d/Id from responseContent output to Variable:NewItem2**. then log the contents of the variables to the workflow history "Here is the item ID of what we just added NewItem =00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 and NewItem2 =00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000.

If I copy the API from the workflow and use the values that are returned in my Workflow log pop it into the browser, there are my values!

Between the time the first API enters the values in the list and I ask for the results of what was entered I run a another API call  to get the WorkFlow subscription ID and pop that value into a variable. **"_api/SP.WorkflowServices.WorkflowSubscriptionService.Current/EnumerateSubscriptionsByList(guid'XXXXXXXX-AAAA-YYYY-BBBB-ZZZZZZZZZZZZ')?select=Id**" to give it time to add the new value into the list.

I am utterly and confounded and I am hoping that a fresh pair of eyes can see an obvious error that I cannot see as I am too invested in the code.

Comment: I am not sure what language/technology you are using to execute your REST calls, but in general those calls are asynchronous.  If you are doing it from JavaScript, for example, you will want to wait until the promise resolves before checking for the existence of your data.

Comment: @willman, I think Kevin is using REST APIs in workflow.

Comment: UPDATE:  By Emailing my self the contents of Variables I have found the source of the error.  This REST call **_api/web/lists(guid'XXXXXXXX-AAAA-YYYY-BBBB-ZZZZZZZZZZZZ')/items?$filter=Title%20eq%20'[%Current Item:Project Title%]'&$top=1&$select=ID**
is returning 2 different Values for ID:
**{"d":{"results":[{"__metadata":{"id":"3cfa5ca7-zzzz-zzzz-zzzz-111111111111","uri":"BLAH.com/_api\/Web\/Lists(guid'9013fd02-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-222222222222')\/Items(50)","etag":"\"1\"","type":"SP.Data......ListItem"},"Id":50,"ID":50}]}}**